# Using Virtualbox with Mainline Kernel

Tags: 18.04, kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

I recently had to switch from the officially supported Ubuntu kernel to one of the newer mainline ones because of a bug related to a hardware driver.

Unfortunately, I can't run virtualbox now because I don't have the necessary kernel modules for the version of the kernel I am running.

Does Virtualbox support all mainline kernels? Or do I have to be on one of the ones that Ubuntu officially supports? If it is possible, how do I do it?

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Which OS, which kernel version, which Virtualbox version and do you get specific error information? What guide are you using to install VB? Please click edit and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with edit –

Comment: No, VirtualBox doesn't support "all mainline kernels".